# Is it possible to change the number of columns of a legend created with FacetGrid.add_legend()?

Tags: seaborn

The following code creates a legend of a facegrid and positions it above:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="col", col_wrap=2, hue='key')
g = g.map(sns.lineplot, 'x', 'y')
g.add_legend()
g._legend.set_bbox_to_anchor((0.5, 1.05))
```

Is there a way to control the number columns? It has a `_ncol` attribute but I haven't seen a method to change it. Changing it manually doesn't do the job.

Comment: You cannot change the number of columns after the legend is created. In turn, I fear this means that you need to create the legend with matplotlib's `.legend()` command.

Answer (score 2):

I found the definition of `add_legend` in the seaborn source code. It accepts `**kwargs` and hands them to `self.figure.legend(...)` or `ax.legend(...)`.

So one can simply pass `ncol=2` as parameter. This should also be a better was to define the position of the legend by using `loc` and/or `bbox_to_anchor` arguments.

Here would is an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", hue="smoker")
g.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip", alpha=.7)
g.add_legend(ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,1.05));
```